# Main menu placement in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am using Intellj IDEA in Linux (with Gnome) I can't seem to find an option to move the main menu from the top of the screen inside the window that it belongs to; this is similar to the appearance that is present in the equivalent Windows version. Anyone has any idea on how to do that? Or is it not supported?

EDIT:

Seeing is everything so...

Ubuntu version:
[image: Ubuntu version]

Windows version:
[image: Windows version]

Hopefully that will give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot?  I've not seen this before.  Are you running on stock Ubuntu or another distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is Global Menu Integration for Swing applications.

You can get normal menus be uninstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove jayatana libjayatana libjayatanaag libjayatana-java libjayatanaag-java
```